# Seo Friendly not working for this script

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

For Some reason i can't implement an url friendly structure on this code.... normally its http://domain.com/users.php?user=username but i would like to change it to http://domain.com/users/dezz
can any of you guys spot where i am going wrong?

```
<?php
/**
 * UserInfo.php
 *
 * This page is for users to view their account information
 * with a link added for them to edit the information.
 *
 * Updated by: The Angry Frog
 * Last Updated: October 26, 2011
 */
include("include/session.php");
global $database;
$config = $database->getConfigs();
if (!isset($_GET['user'])) { 
    header("Location: ".$config['WEB_ROOT'].$config['home_page']);
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $config['SITE_NAME']; ?></title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    font: 12px/1.5 Lucida Grande, Arial, Helvetica, 'Liberation Sans', FreeSans, sans-serif;    
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* Requested Username error checking */
$req_user = trim($_GET['user']);
if(!$req_user || strlen($req_user) == 0 ||
   !preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]([0-9a-z_-\s])+$/i", $req_user) ||
   !$database->usernameTaken($req_user)){
   die("Username not registered");
}

/* Logged in user viewing own account */
if(strcmp($session->username,$req_user) == 0){
   echo "<h1>My Account</h1>";
}
/* Visitor not viewing own account */
else{
   echo "<h1>User Info</h1>";
}

/* Display requested user information - add/delete as applicable */
$req_user_info = $database->getUserInfo($req_user);

/* Username */
echo "<b>Username: ".$req_user_info['username']."</b><br>";

/* Email */
echo "<b>Email:</b> ".$req_user_info['email']."<br>";

/**
 * Note: when you add your own fields to the users table
 * to hold more information, like homepage, location, etc.
 * they can be easily accessed by the user info array.
 *
 * $session->user_info['location']; (for logged in users)
 *
 * $req_user_info['location']; (for any user)
 */

/* If logged in user viewing own account, give link to edit */
if(strcmp($session->username,$req_user) == 0){
   echo '<br><a href="useredit.php">Edit Account Information</a><br>';
}

/* Link back to main */
echo "<br>Back To [<a href='".$config['WEB_ROOT'].$config['home_page']."'>Main</a>]<br>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

and the .htaccess structure

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule users/([0-9]+)/ users.php?user=$1
```

Comment: `[0-9]` is numbers only, you need `[a-zA-Z0-9]` most likely, asuming you don't use special chars

Comment: `/users/dezz` is text, but you're allowing only numbers.

Comment: added `[a-zA-Z0-9]` but it still returns a 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is only matching numbers in username. Change your rule to:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /beta1/

RewriteRule ^users/(\w+)/?$ users.php?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: seems to have no affect since its returning a 404 error

Comment: The requested URL /users.php was not found on this server. yet the file does exist

Comment: http://dezz.tv/beta1/users/dezzer the original structure is `http://dezz.tv/beta1/users.php?user=dezzer`

Comment: Ah you never told about presence of `/beta1/` folder. See my updated answer now.